# How can I conceive all this (Python, networking, VM)

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, virtual-machine

I have developed a software that receives user requests.

I forward those requests on a VM where Windows is installed.

The Windows VM is safeless (no anti-virus, no firewall ...) in order to check if the user requests are dangerous (attacks) or not.

To be more precise, my clients will test their websites for vulnerabilities using my software.

My software surveys the actions on that VM in order to inform the users if their website is malicious or not.

My VM must answers me back if "nothing bad has happened".

My problem:

What if one of those requests harms my VM: I must satisfy the user requests while my software will need to communicate with my VM ? Or is there a way to monitor the behavior of the user's websites on my VM without harming it ?

An other important question: is a malicious website able to crash my Windows VM ?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to put an AV and firewall on the VM and then see if they trigger to determine if the website is dangerous?

Comment: That is a good idea, but I prefer not to rely on commercial tools or other third party tools.

Comment: How do you quantify "dangerous"? Either you rely on other companies' algorithms or you write your own.

Comment: "dangerous" == malware hosted on the website of a user who wants to check the safety of his website by sending a request to my software which will forward it to a VM to be executed/scanned there

Comment: How do you know whether something is malware?

Comment: I do not know in advance because I am not a God and I hate Gods. My software will scan the websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what VM you are using. I assume you want to use some VM like [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

VM is just a software implementation of an operating system. So, basically it will do almost all the the things what a normal OS can do if it has enough resources like memory and I/O devices. But there are some limitations too with the VM. For eg: VM can't access the graphics card of the host system. So, you can't play high graphic games on them as you would do on a normal system.

Coming to your question:

> What if one of those requests harms my VM: I must satisfy the user
>   requests while my software will need to communicate with my VM ? Or is
>   there a way to monitor the behavior of the user's websites on my VM
>   without harming it ?

As VM just behave like a normal OS, so if the OS installed in your VM s vulnerable to a particular vulnerability then it will surely get infected. But in case of some VM like VMware you can create a [snapshot](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015180) that will save the current state of the VM. Then try to execute your experiments, if something goes wrong you can revert back to the initial state by using the snap shot feature.

> An other important question: is a malicious website able to crash my
>   Windows VM ?

Yes, if the Windows installed in the VM is vulnerable. Be sure that there are also some attacks known as [Side-Channel attacks](https://www.google.com/#q=side+channel+attacks+in+vm) that can exploit the memory of a Guest system in VM and gain access to the memory of the Host system.

Also in you case an other solution can be the use of [honeypots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29).

Comment: I validated your answer because you gave me some hints. But maybe I will bother you by some questions later in the future if I may. Thank you (I am using VirtualBox)